# Is there a way to see which thread is printing to stdout or stderr with gdb?

Tags: c++, multithreading, gdb

I am debugging a multithreaded application with gdb.

I can see the threads, and play switch / break with them, but sometimes when I am attached to a particular thread, some of the other threads print something.

How can I find out which thread is printing what part?

Answer (score 1):

Aside from setting breakpoints at strategic places [printf, fprintf, write, or some such], I suppose you could prefix (or postfix) any printf with a thread-id (but you would probably need to add that manually for every printf - or ones that you need to know about at least).

If you are using `cout` rather than printf, it may be a bit easier, as you could do (something as ugly as) something like this:

```
#define cout cout << pthread_self() << ":"
```

Although it may cause a few issues with things like `cout.flush()` or `cout.setprecision()`.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to set conditional breakpoint on `write` system call with FD number in condition and stop at this breakpoint.
The exact condition depends on architecture you are using.

For 64-bit x86 it can be:

```
(gdb) catch syscall write
(gdb) condition 1 $rdi==1
```

For 32-bit:

```
(gdb) catch syscall write
(gdb) condition 1 $ebx==1
```

These examples are for stdout. For stderr, condition will change slightly, for example `(gdb) condition 1 $rdi==2`.

After that done you can easily see thread number either from `info threads` output or manually call `pthread_self()` like this:

```
(gdb) p pthread_self()
```